# Can't add the build in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my `iOS` application to `iTunes Connect`. I want to submit it for review but in the `Build` section the add button is not yet displayed even if I have uploaded my application almost an hour even if I refreshed the page. Is that normal? I have searched about this and found that it takes 10 or 15 minutes. From where can I check the status of my uploaded build?

Comment: It is totally up to Apple. It can take more than hours if you didn't see any error while uploading. You can see uploaded binary when you click `Add` button from app meta setting.

Comment: Thank you @Ryan, I'm afraid of having the status inactive so I'm refreshing the page every time. I didn't get any errors, the validation and the upload was success. Please, from where can I access to the Add button that you said?

Comment: Apple will send you an email when the uploaded build is ready. Only then will you see the + button next to Build in iTunes Connect. Typically this only takes 10-20 minutes but it can sometimes takes several hours.

Comment: @rmaddy I deleted the answer I added. The `+` button doesn't appear until there's at least one available binary.

Comment: @rmaddy what about the "inactive" status? Supposing that Apple enables me to add the build in iTunes Connect and I didn't see it just after some hours. What will happen in this case?

Comment: @Llg, if binary disappears after uploading on itunes, Apple send an email to the registered mail address. this is because of missing privacy information in .plist file of app. They also write that which key you are missing in the plist file . you will get it in mail.